# Correct solution of $z$ to equations $z^3 + \bar{w}^{7} = 0$ and $z^5 w^{11} = 1$

Tags: complex-numbers, systems-of-equations

> We need to find the $z$ from the given 2 equations; $z^3 + \bar{w}^{7} = 0$ and $z^5 w^{11} = 1$ where $w$ is the cube root of unity.

**My Try -:**

From the first equation, $z^3 + w^{14} = 0 \rightarrow z^3 + w^{2} = 0 \ as \ \bar{w} = w^2 \ and \ w^3 = 1$

From the second equation, $z^5 = w$

Using above equations, we can write $z^2(-w^2) = w$ from using value of $z$ from equation $1$ and putting in equation $2$, we get $ z^2 + w^2 = 0 \rightarrow z = \pm iw$

But $z = \pm iw$ does not seem to be the correct answer as the textbook shows the correct answer as **$\pm i$.**

**Attached is the solution from where this question is taken:**

> If complex numbers satisfy the system of equations $z^3+\overline{\omega^7}=0$ and $z^5 \omega^{11}=1$, then find $z$.
> $$\text{Sol. } z^3+\bar{\omega}^7=0$$
> $$
> \begin{array}{ll}
> \Rightarrow & z^3=-\bar{\omega}^7 \\
> \Rightarrow & |z|^3=|-\bar{\omega}|^7=|\omega|^7 \\
> \Rightarrow & |z|^{15}=|\omega|^{35}  \qquad \qquad \qquad \,\,\,(1)\\
> \text { Alśo, } & z^5 \omega^{11}=1 \\
> \Rightarrow & |z|^5|\omega|^{11}=1 \\
> \Rightarrow & |z|^{15}|\omega|^{33}=1 \qquad \qquad \qquad (2)\\
> \end{array}
> $$
> From $(1)$ and $(2)$, we have
> $$
> |z|=|\omega|=1
> $$
> Again, $\bar{\omega}^7=-z^3 \quad$ and $\quad \omega^{11}=z^{-5}$
> $$
> \begin{array}{ll}
> \Rightarrow & \bar{\omega}^{77} \cdot \omega^{77}=-z^{33} \cdot z^{-35} \\
> \Rightarrow & z^2=-1=i^2 \Rightarrow z= \pm i
> \end{array}
> $$

Please help me find the solutions to this problem. Thanks in advance!

Comment: $\pm i$ cannot satisfy $z^5=\omega$ since $i^5=i \neq \omega$. Hence I suspect a typo somewhere.

Comment: Added the screenshot. Check it out now!

Comment: The screenshot is missing the crucial information. Obviously $\omega$ is not a third root of unity, because that would give $z^5\omega^{11}=i\cdot \omega^2\neq 1$. So what is $\omega$? The solution shows that $\omega^{11}=-i$, so $\omega^{44}=1$. But the first equation then gives a contradiction.

Comment: So, does that mean that question is wrong?

Comment: And your solution, $z=iw$ would give $1=z^5w^{11}=(iw)^5w^{11}=iw^{16}$. Is the question wrong? To answer this, we first need the complete question. With $\omega^3=1$ it is wrong. But this is not in the screeshot. In any case, it is incomplete.

Comment: This is the complete screenshot. The question ends at $z  = \pm i$.

Comment: Exatly. So you don't know about $\omega$. Then its time for you to look for it, before claiming that the book is wrong (which might be true of course).

Comment: How are you coming up with $w^3=1$?

Comment: Hint: equate two expressions for $z^{15}$ to evaluate $w^2$, then use $z=(z^3)^2/z^5$.